# Add public transport details to Google Maps (Cracow)

Tags: google-maps

I would like to know if any of you have added public transport to Google Maps. I live in Cracow, Poland and I'm fed up with not having it there. I was once reading about adding geo location of bus stops and so on.

Could single non-related-to-the-city-transport enterprise deal with it and if so, how?

And what about time schedule, is there any way to make it synchronize itself with the official site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transport companies or authorities wanting to provide their data to Google, must do so themselves.

See the Google [Transit Partner program](http://maps.google.com/help/maps/mapcontent/transit/)

Comment: I'm not sure that it's only companies:   in some cases, it's municipal authorities who are responsible for transport in their area, no matter who provides it, who can provide the data.

Comment: True. Edited to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that a single individual not related to the city transport enterprise cannot do this.   Among other things, you will not have access to the official data feed from the bus company, and so you might not keep it up to date.

(I looked into this a while ago, when I set up a website with maps of my city's bus-routes because the transport enterprise hadn't done that.   Thankfully our enterprise has now done that, and has also put data into Google Tranzit.)